# Como criar relacionamentos sem ter que inserir objetos inteiros?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Estou um pouco confuso quanto ao spring, pois apesar de fazer um mapeamento de entidade/objetos, ele me obriga a toda vez repassar um 2 objeto no cadastro, como assim?
Por exemplo existe 2 tabelas/modelos, um usuário e o outro empregado. O empregado teria funcionalidades adicionais, pois, um usuário poderia ser um empregado em um ou mais postos, para fazer esse mapeamento eu passo:

@ManyToOne
@JoinCollumn
Usuario usuario

sendo que ao fazer o cadastro eu tenho que passar o objeto, teria como eu apenas passar o código de identificação e fazer esse mapeamento?

Answer (score 0):

Felipe, nos relacionamentos @ManyToOne você pode passar o objeto apenas com o id, mas esse objeto tem que existir no banco de dados, no spring isso funciona quando vc vai persistir, agora quando for realizar um merge isso já não funciona precisa fazer um findByid e setar o objeto completo

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).